# Testcafe request with cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, typescript, cypress, testcafe

I am trying to find a method in testcafes API similar to Cypress' request.

Cypress' [request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Cookies) will attach any cookies to the request that already exist in the browser so that http requests will look like they're being made from the browser / user.

Is there a similar function in testcafe?

Answer (score 6):

You can modify your cookies using the [ClientFunctions](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402832/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info) mechanism. These cookies will be added to further requests. This approach is safe, since every test in TestCafe starts with clear cookies, so cookies modification will not affect other tests.
I prepared an example, please see it:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

const setCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
    document.cookie = "myCustomCookie=myCustomValue";
});

fixture `fixture`
    .page `http://google.com`;

test(`1`, async t => {
    await setCookie();

    await t.typeText('input[type=text]', 'test');

    await t.debug();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please also take a look at https://azevedorafaela.com/2019/07/24/inject-cookies-in-your-testcafe-automation/?source=post_page--------------------------- . That article can be useful for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

TestCafe 1.20.0+ offers the [`t.request` method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403981/reference/test-api/testcontroller/request) - it is designed for API testing. Using this method, you can incorporate API testing right into your existing functional TestCafe tests. Read about this feature in the [corresponding guide](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403971/guides/intermediate-guides/api-testing).
If you'd like to attach a cookie to the request, you can use the `withCredentials` [option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403971/guides/intermediate-guides/api-testing#receive-credentials).

Please note that to get/set/delete cookies in tests, you can use TestCafe's [cookie management API](https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management) (works for 'HTTPOnly' as well).