# Checking if no Cookie exists and if a Cookie exists, delete the Cookie in Testcafe

Tags: testing, cookies, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am new to Testcafé and working on a Testcase to check if no Cookies exist beforehand and if there is a cookie, to delete the Cookie. I have checked [this](https://azevedorafaela.com/2019/07/24/inject-cookies-in-your-testcafe-automation/?source=post_page---------------------------) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032137/testcafe-request-with-cookies) post but don´t see any option on how to check if a cookie does exist or does not exist, as the posts describe on how to set a Cookie.

My first implementation would look like this:

```
    import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
    
    const setCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
      if (document.cookie.length!==0)
{
document.cookie = 'COOKIE_NAME=; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=' + location.host;
}
    });
    
    fixture `fixture`
        .page `http://google.com`;
    
    test(`1`, async t => {
        await setCookie();
    
        await t.typeText('input[type=text]', 'test');
    
        await t.debug();
    });
```

I checked the Testcafé API but didn't find any corresponding method; hence, any help or hints would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How about just delete all cookies and then fire up the test? Conditions make your tests more difficult, that means more risk you'll eventually get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TestCafe 1.19.0 version there is no need to create excessive *Client Functions* to interact with browser cookies. Our cookie management API offers a flexible and convenient way to set, get, or delete page cookies regardless of the `HttpOnly` flag status. You can learn more here https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this thread: [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
It has a good code sample that demonstrates how you can parse \ clear cookies.
You can use this code in your ClientFunction as a starting point to detect and clear a specific cookie.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.